# Software and methods used in LIDAR data visualization?

Tags: meteorology, remote-sensing, software, visualization

I was assigned a task to prepare a report which states the current state of the art in Doppler wind LIDAR (DWL) visualization and visualization tools used in meteorology. In the last 3 days I've tried my best to find useful resources to prepare a report utilizing some known sites (e.g. google scholar, JURN, Scopus and few others), with not much success.

Are there any research papers which explain 3D interactive visualization in Doppler WIND LIDAR or LIDAR technology?

Comment: Windows or Linux Software? Might you include an example graphic, which is similar to those that you want to create?

Comment: @daniel.neumann I am preparing small report which explains current state of the art 3D interactive visualization techniques used in Doppler wind lidar technology or simple lidar technology. I want to get an idea from few research papers which state about interactive visualization in meteorology currently.  I tried different sites like google scholar etc and I found few papers, but I thought maybe I get some hints from meteorology people here so that I can refine my report.